# CSS flex layout overflow issue - not 100% of nested content can be scrolled

Tags: css, angular, angular-flex-layout

I have a problem with flexlayout and overflow. Here you can see my Problem:

[image]

The icons are not 100% scrollable. I have absolutely no clue how to fix this. In theory, I think everything should be correct. I use Angular, Angular FlexLayout, Custom CSS. The Icons are grouped using flexlayout="column" and flexlayoutalign="space-around center" and everything is encapsulated with a div flexlayout="row", flexlayoutalign="space-around center". This row is now not fully recognized by my overflow CSS variable using custom CSS. Here are my classes. First, I set a fixed boundary for the popup (one hierarchy-level over the mat-card), and the latter is added to the mat-content section of the mat-card.

CSS for the Popup:

```
.max-height:{
   max-height: 500px;
 }
```

CSS for mat-content:

```
:host{
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
mat-dialog-content{
  max-height: unset !important;
}
.example-card{
  height: inherit;
}
.mat-card-content{
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.min-width-icons{

       min-width: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Edit:// here are inspection figures:

[image]
[image]

Edit:// if I set a fixed height on the icons, e.g., 50px, the icons move out the upper boundary even more:

[image]

Edit://
issue persists even if i use png/jpg:

[image]

Edit://
Maybe it has something to do that the description class is adding word-break: break-all; But, either I do not how to counter that.

Edit://
Ugh this is some nasty CSS sh... got it working! It has something to do with the overflow-wrap/word-break of the underlying description:

[image]

As far as I noticed is that everything got better after i added width/min-widt of 100%. After that, i tried to set the height value to 100% (not worked). But, as far as i add a height in px (every value from 1px to 2000px) everything works as expect, which makes absolutely no sense to me, maybe some CSS mastermind can me pin point the reason. Field height is marked in black and green is the overflow word-break.

But, for now the problem seems to be solved with this css:

```
.text-area{
  word-break: break-all;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Are the icons SVG ?

Comment: mat-icon and google fonts are used, I think they are svgs

Comment: I know that for SVG, the beggining of the element in html is counted from the Viewbox, which mean that if your icon is not perfectly center and the size of you viewbox, the svg might get cutted (in your case at the top). So It's worth it to check indivuadally your icons and to check if they take the full size of the viewbox, if it is,  it's an issue to resolve directly in the svg file. Let me know as I ran in this issue with SVG quite often, if it's something else not sure i'l; be much help

Comment: added image with fixed height to the icons. The problem still persists.

Comment: To be noted that if you use a sprite sheet, it also works with viewbox so you have to make sure your X and Y line where you define your viewbox (with the css line background position) is perfecty imaching the px of sprite sheet (again because it's cutted at the top, you probably have an issue with your Y line)

Comment: Ah if you're using jpg or png with fixed height and width and the problem is still here then i don't know where the problem can come from :/ maybe some dirty margin or padding

Comment: Try adding flex-grow: 1; to the icons containers, actually how i see it here is you defined a max height for your flex parents, and some of its children don't have place to grow as the text container is taking most of the height, By adding flex grow you allow one container to grow in priority compare to others. But with the overflow scroll, it shouldnt happen actually lol So i don't know. Hope you'll find fast, good luck man!

Comment: tried your suggestions with jpg/pngs - did not work as u can see. now i try the flex grow variant. No Luck with flex="grow" on the columns and or flex="grow/no-shrink" on the flex row with all icons.

Comment: What about max-height: 300px; for mat-card-content ? I see in your inspector that it's 300px of height, so the max is already taken. What if you increase this value or remove the line completely ?

Comment: Could you share it on codepen ? i got curious about this issue now lol

Comment: Well, this issue can be related to angular, its CSS, the material lib or leaflet, which is used for the map in the background, and the popup. Currently, I have no time to provide codepen, because it involves a bit of work to do so and make the problem reproducible in a standalone fashion. For now, my problem is fixed, but the reason is beyond my mind.